# Pagination using java

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, pagination

This is code for pagination in java i tried to implement. i have 20 records with columns emp_id and emp_name which i want to display using 4 pages i.e (5 records per page) using my sql workbench but code is not executing indicating many errors plz solve this

```
<%@ page import ="java.io.*, java.sql.*, java.util.*" %>
<%!

Connection con = null;  
ResultSet rs = null;    
ResultSet rs1 = null;   
int start_row_count, end_row_count, no_of_page, pages;  
String page_name="paging.jsp";

%>

<html>
<head>
 </head>

<body>
<table border="1" style="width:80%;">
<%

try
{
    String pages1=request.getParameter("pages");

    if(pages1!=null)
    {
        pages=Integer.parseInt(pages1);
    }

    if(pages==0)   
        pages=1;

    if(pages==1)
    {
        start_row_count=1;
    }
    else
    {
        start_row_count=(pages-1)*5;
    }

    end_row_count=pages*5;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shelu", "root", "mysql");

    String sql="select * from emp limit" + start_row_count +"5";

    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs.next())
    {%>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getInt("emp_id")%></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString("emp_name")%></td>
    </tr>
<%  
    }

    rs.close();
    rs1=st.executeQuery("select count(*) from emp");

    int total=0;

    if(rs1.next())
        total=rs1.getInt(1);

    if(total%5==0)
        no_of_page=total/5;
    else
        no_of_page=total/5+1;

%>

<tr>

<%

for(int i=1;i<=no_of_page;i++)
{
    out.println("<a href='"+page_name+"?pages="+i+"'>"+i+"</a>");
}

 %>

 </tr>

 <%

 } catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 %>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all scriptlets are bad , next thing is please post the errors !

Comment: you need to use limit x offset y in your sql command

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at server side pagination, [Displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/) is what you should be using.

Comment: Check the tutorial section in Displaytag's website. http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_basic.html